# OpenVPN route to other local IP Address than PC

Tags: networking, openvpn

I have VPS with server OpenVPN.
iptables rules on VPS:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 54000 -j DNAT --to 10.8.0.2:8080
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.8.0.2 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

Actually it works like that:

- I connect to OpenVPN from PC
- Port 8080 from PC is forwarded to VPS and i can connect it via web: 51.xx.xx.xx:54000

What i need:

- I connect to OpenVPN from PC
- Port 8080 from Camera is forwarded to VPS and i can connect it via web: 51.xx.xx.xx:54000

It is possible?

Setup:

- Router: 192.168.100.1
- PC: 192.168.100.164
- Camera: 192.168.100.165

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Use a reverse proxy (for example NGINX) at your PC which points to the camera. Then you can forward the port of your reverse proxy to your VPS.

Comment: Ok, now HTTP it's working, but i can't do RTSP with this method on port 554, why? It's possible using NGINX?

Comment: It says "rtsp://admin:xxxxx@51.xx.xx.xxx:XXXX: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: In default NGINX only does reverse proxy for HTTP and maybe HTTPS. Additional protocols have to be configured. Ask Google and take a look into the documentation.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much :).